# MySQL command line issues

Tags: mysql, command-line-interface

I am trying to create a mysql cron job to export a DB table as a csv from yesterday

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(date_created) = DATETIME(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)' at line 1`

```
mysql -u db_user -pPASSWORD -h 00.00.00.00 db_name -B -e "select * FROM emailsignup_signup WHERE DATETIME(date_created) = DATETIME(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY);" | sed 's/\t/","/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/;s/\n//g' > /var/www/subscribers/subscribers+date+"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S".csv
```

I've tried adding brackets around the variables, and escaping the parentheses. 
I simply cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong to get this error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(date_created) = DATETIME(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)' at line 1
```

Comment: what is the type of the `date_created` column?

Comment: what's the actual query?

Comment: its in there "select * FROM emailsignup_signup WHERE DATETIME(date_created) = DATETIME(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY);" and the type is datetime. The query works in phpmyadmin, just not command line

Comment: Try `DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)`

Comment: There's no `DATETIME()` function in MySQL. I'll bet you actually used `DATE()` in PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: That also makes more sense. Using `DATETIME()` will only list the users who signed up exactly 24 hours before the query, to the exact second, not any time during that day.